# Filtering based on a newly created column

Tags: sql, t-sql

(I've looked it up and couldn't find an answer, If this is a duplicate, just point out a link and I'll delete this question)

Let's say I have the following code

```
select CASE WHEN lower(Http_User_Agent) like '%mobi%' then 'Mobile' 
            else 'Desktop' end as Device
from Http_User_Agent
where Device = 'Mobile'
```

Which returns

```
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 4
Invalid column name 'Device'.
```

What I'm basically trying to do is to filter by the newly created column `Device`. Is there an easy way to this?

I'm using SQL server 2008 on windows 7

Comment: Http_User_Agent is a column in Http_User_Agent table?

Comment: @Deepshikha they are both table and column

Comment: Looks like a valid question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

At the time of execution of the query, the `Device` alias isn't yet assigned to the resultset. So you need to either do this:

```
SELECT 
  CASE WHEN LOWER(Http_User_Agent) LIKE '%mobi%' THEN 'Mobile' 
  ELSE 'Desktop' 
  END AS Device
FROM Http_User_Agent
WHERE 
  CASE WHEN LOWER(Http_User_Agent) LIKE '%mobi%' THEN 'Mobile' 
  ELSE 'Desktop' 
  END = 'Mobile'
```

...i.e. not reference the new alias at all. Or this

```
SELECT * 
FROM
(SELECT 
  CASE WHEN LOWER(Http_User_Agent) LIKE '%mobi%' THEN 'Mobile' 
  ELSE 'Desktop' 
  END AS Device
FROM Http_User_Agent)
WHERE Device = 'Mobile'
```

...i.e reference it from a surrounding select

Comment: Your first option works great (you''ll need to remove an extra  parentheses in `FROM` though), while your second code give me an error `Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WHERE'.`. I like your second option better, can you fixed it please?

Comment: I believe you need to name the new table, i.e.SELECT * 
FROM
(SELECT 
  CASE WHEN LOWER(Http_User_Agent) LIKE '%mobi%' THEN 'Mobile' 
  ELSE 'Desktop' 
  END AS Device
FROM Http_User_Agent) as tempTable
WHERE Device = 'Mobile'

Answer (score 4):

You can do this with a subquery:

```
select ua.*
from (select ua.*,
             (CASE WHEN lower(Http_User_Agent) like '%mobi%' then 'Mobile'
                   else 'Desktop'
              end) as Device
      from Http_User_Agent ua
     ) ua
where Device = 'Mobile';
```

Or by repeating the condition:

```
select ua.*,
       (CASE WHEN lower(Http_User_Agent) like '%mobi%' then 'Mobile'
             else 'Desktop'
        end) as Device
from Http_User_Agent ua
where lower(Http_User_Agent) like '%mobi%';
```

However, you cannot use a column alias in a `where` at the same level where it is defined.  This is part of the ANSI standard and not a "limitation" of SQL Server (or any other database).

Answer (score 1):

> It is not allowable to refer to a column alias in a WHERE clause, because the column value might not yet be determined when the WHERE clause is executed.

So you have to write that `case` statement again in your `where` clause.